# ASP .Net Core 2.1 API Template with role based authorization

Tags: restful-authentication, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I wanted to create an ASP .Net Core 2.1 REST server. For that I created a new project and choosed the "API" Template. I got it working with Entity Framework, a simple SQlite database and some GET and POST calls.

Now I'd like to add authorization (role based) to the API. I read about the Identity stuff but I just don't get it working. Is there any good tutorial or can somebody tell me how I can add authorization to my REST server? My database context already has a table "User" for the user information... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If not already seen (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) is well worth a look.I'm not aware of tutorials involving SQLite and Identity though have used embedded databases without problems in other Net Core apps. The Visual Studio 2017 Net Core Template using "Individual User Accounts" option adds authentication/authorization out of the box for SQL Server (Express) database with a set of login/logout razor pages. The Identity tables are quite specific and generally populated by migrations. You may find it useful to scaffold the Identity razor pages by right-clicking the project "Add => New Scafolded Item => Identity" The ApplicationModel.cs model class is used to customise the AspNetUsers table. These can all be reverse engineered using "EF Core Power Tools" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) and recreated in another database using a custom context (eg WCX_IdentityContext.cs) by selecting "Reverse Engineer" from right-click menu. Typically you can access via the context as shown below

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // The home page is redirected dependent on currently logged in user details stored in the Identity tables.
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        using (var context = new WCX_IdentityContext())
        {
            // Use Identity and EF core to retrieve logged on user details
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;

            // The AspNetUsers Identity table contains the basic identity details
            var user = context.AspNetUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == identity.Name);
```

I hope this helps you getting started.